# Регулярное выражение для ссылок

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Имеется текст такого вида (количество ссылок в строке бывает от 0 до 10):

```
различный html текст с различными символами
[url=http://img.site.kz/upload_image/000.JPG]
[img=left]http://img.site.kz/upload_image/thumb/000.JPG[/img][/url]
опять html код
[url=http://img.site.kz/upload_image/111.JPG]
[img=left]http://img.site.kz/upload_image/thumb/111.JPG[/img][/url]
```

Нужно получить в итоге массив такого рода (чтобы в нем были ссылки из кода из тега `url`):

```
Array (
 [0] => http://img.site.kz/upload_image/000.JPG
 [1] => http://img.site.kz/upload_image/111.JPG
)
```

Либо вывести текст, что нет ссылок.

Как это сделать с помощью регулярного выражения?

Comment: А какие символы могут быть в ссылках? Например, ссылки вида `http://localhost/?param[]=123` (или аналогичное) может присутствовать?  И как тогда определять, что `param[]` - это часть ссылки, а не `param[` и закрывающая скобка ссылки?

Comment: Символы лишь такие, как в примере. Путь к картинке, в котором меняется имя файлв

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "различный html текст с различными символами  [url=http://img.site.kz/upload_image/000.JPG][img=left]http://img.site.kz/upload_image/thumb/000.JPG[/img][/url] опять html код [url=http://img.site.kz/upload_image/111.JPG][img=left]http://img.site.kz/upload_image/thumb/111.JPG[/img][/url] ";



$pattern = '|(http://[a-zA-Z0-9_\./]+)|'; 
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches , PREG_PATTERN_ORDER ) ) { 
    $res= $matches[0];
    print_r($res); 
} else {
    echo ("нет ссылок");
}
```

Comment: А если ссылка будет содержать знак вопроса, либо закрывающую квадратную скобку?

Comment: $pattern = '|(http://[a-zA-Z0-9_\./?%]+)|';  А символ ']' в ссылках не может присутствовать

Comment: Если не нужны ссылки с [img=left], тогда:  $pattern = '|url=(http://[a-zA-Z0-9_\./?%]+)|';

Comment: или $pattern = '|\[url=(\w+?[^\]]*\])|';

Comment: Не нужны ссылки с [img=left], но |url=(http://[a-zA-Z0-9_\./?%]+)| сохраняет в массив еще и "url=" А |[url=(\w+?[^]]*])| не работает

Comment: @sva, ошибаетесь: создаем файл `index.php` с содержимым `var_dump($_REQUEST);` и вызываем этот файл через `localhost/index.php?name[]=123`. В выводе увидим, что `name` - это массив, т.к. после его имени стоит `[]` Но судя по комменту автора, ссылки, ломающие вашу регулярку, не будут присутствовать

Comment: @bullet2018, если в ссылках всегда отсутствует знак `]`, то можно использовать следующий паттерн: `$pattern = '|(?<=\[url=)[^\]]+|';` - он выбирает весь текст между `[url=` и первой закрывающей скобкой `]`

Comment: @BOPOH Cпасибо. Этот паттерн подходит |(?<=[url=)[^]]+| А то я уже через substr стал вырезать лишние символы url= А можете еще подсказать как удалить из строки подобный код '[ url=http://img.site.kz/upload_image/000.JPG][ img=left]http://img.site.kz/upload_image/thumb/000.JPG[/ img][/ url]' То есть все эти ссылки и картинки. От [url= до [/url] включительно

Comment: @sva Cпасибо. Этот паттерн подходит |(?<=[url=)[^]]+| А то я уже через substr стал вырезать лишние символы url= А можете еще подсказать как удалить из строки подобный код '[ url=http://img.site.kz/upload_image/000.JPG][ img=left]http://img.site.kz/upload_image/thumb/000.JPG[/ img][/ url]' То есть все эти ссылки и картинки. От [url= до [/url] включительно

Answer (score 1):

В общем решилась моя задача вот так:

```
$str = "различный html текст с различными символами  [url=http://img.site.kz/upload_image/000.JPG][img=left]http://img.site.kz/upload_image/thumb/000.JPG[/img][/url] опять html код [url=http://img.site.kz/upload_image/111.JPG][img=left]http://img.site.kz/upload_image/thumb/111.JPG[/img][/url] ";

$pattern = '|(?<=\[url=)[^\]]+|'; 
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches , PREG_PATTERN_ORDER ) ) { 
    $res= $matches[0];
    print_r($res); 
} else {
    echo ("нет ссылок");
}
```

И удалил из строки лишние ссылки

```
$str=preg_replace('#\[url=.*\[\/url\]#sUi', '', $str);
```